# Как принимать входящие GET-запросы и получать параметры GET'а?

Tags: java, http, get

Приложение принимает сообщения в виде GET-запросов в реальном времени. Само приложение запросы не отправляет: лишь приём. Подскажите какие классы, библиотеки можно использовать.

Comment: стандартный http сервер

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html